# Working of map with UDT(user defined type) in cassandra

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Let's say I have a **product table** in Cassandra and **Information UDT**

```
Create table Product{
    id text,
    details map<text,<frozen<Information>>,
    detailsMore list<frozen<Information>>
}
Create Type Information{
    info1 text,
    info2 text
}
```

For these, I have two classes in **Java** as

```
@Table
Class Product{
String id;
Map<String, Information> details;
List<Information> details;
}
@UserDefinedType('Information')
Class Information{
String info1;
String info2;
}
```

---

Now I fetch data using CRUDRepository(spring) and now I am like

```
Product prodObj = repo.find(id);
```

Now this prodObj contains data like

```
details map<String,UDTValue>,
detailsMore list<Information>
```

**Why user-defined type is converted to Information in case of List but it wasn't converted in case of Map? Or I am doing something wrong?**. If I directly try to assign this UDTValue of Map to Information I get the below exception(obvious).
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.core.UDTValue cannot be cast to Information

Answer (score 1):

You need to write custom codec for your class that will map `UDTValue` into your `Information` class.  Please refer to [Java Driver documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/custom_codecs/) (I don't want to copy their code as illustration).

**Update after providing example**: I'm not familiar with Spring Cassandra Mapper, but you get the same functionality directly using the [Object Mapper from Java Driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/object_mapper/).  You need to mark the class that represents user-defined type with `@UDT` annotation, and driver will take care for it.  I've created the working example - it's available [here](https://gist.github.com/alexott/6e6fd8b0eca717f9f10984c9de75123b) (see `output` part for result of execution).

Comment: Is that the way, I mean It fails only in case of Map<String, Information> whereas for the direct class Information it looks to works fine.

Comment: I use @org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.UserDefinedType on the type declared and it maps perfectly. But the same doesn't work when inside a map.

Comment: updated the question with more details, hope somebody can help me now.

Comment: I've updated the answer - unfortunately I'm not familiar with Spring mapper... And it's not officially supported...

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing the way! I am amazed to see u wrote code to answer. But looks it's not supported for spring presently. Have to work the other way out.see ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027241/sprint-data-cassandra-mapping-of-map-with-user-defined-type-fails-with-not-of-t & https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-487

Comment: But why you're forced to use Spring? Why not use Java driver directly? P.S. it's not a problem to write a code :-)

Comment: I would have changed that map to a list if it was in my hand :P ... the structure and architecture is pre-decided. I am writing a converter as in example 10 of (https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.datastax.driver.core.UDTValue) for now and research more to find more optimal solution :)

Comment: Yes, in the present project... It's on spring-boot, Cassandra and googles cloud.

Comment: But `spring-boot` doesn't imply `spring-data-cassandra` and `spring-data-cassandra` has java driver as dependency, so you can use it directly...